# PowerShell: Create local user account on target machine without beeing administrator

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I try to create a local user account on a remote machine. For connecting the PowerShell session I'm using a local user on the target machine. This user is not part of the local Administrator group but it's part of a local group which has been granted full privileges on the default PowerShell session configuration. The target machine isn't part of a domain.

The folder creation on the target machine works, so I'm sure the user can run local PowerShell commands successfully. But the ADSI command is failing. I guess because it needs to be run with local Administrator rights. Any idea how I could solve this scenario without remoting in with a local Administrator account?

Script:

```
$cred = IMPORT-CLIXML C:\temp\credentials.xml
$mySession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $targetMachine -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $mySession -ScriptBlock {
    New-Item -Path "c:\test" -ItemType Directory
    $cn = [ADSI]"WinNT://${env:Computername}"
    $userObject = $cn.Create("User","testUser")
}
```

If I add the local user that's used for remoting to the Administrator group all works fine. But I'd like to avoid using a Administrator account to make it more secure.

Comment: why cant you check google!
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/46ddbacd-53a0-4979-bdf6-b6961c742dfc/problem-creating-local-accounts-using-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you are local or on a remote machine via PowerShell remoting, a non-administrator account can not create new user accounts.

So the problem is not that there is no PowerShell cmdlet to add users, `ADSI` or `net user` work just fine, but you have to be an administrator.

I tried to remote in as a normal user and then execute a command elevated as an admin on the remote machine. Neither `Start-Process` no `psexec.exe` worked.

There may be third party tools that can do this, but you would have to provide a user name and password to them.

Using the [JEA toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn896648.aspx) seems to be the cleanest approach, but it has a bit of a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

The remote execution will work but the code being ran on the other side is broken

```
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:computername,computer"
$newuser = $computer.Create("user", "NewUser1")
$newuser.SetPassword("Password1")
$newuser.SetInfo()
```

this would make a new local user so just run this code on the remote machine.

Comment: check this out http://superuser.com/questions/644510/powershell-remoting-as-non-administrator

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The remoting with the non-administrator user to execute PowerShell works fine but not the ADSI part. If I add the local remoting user to the Administrator group the ADSI part works as well. The problem is more about the ADSI part and a non-administrator user (which has full permission on the used default session configuration). This means ADSI code is okay and non-administrator user can connect to execute PowerShell. But not the combination of both.

Comment: the adsi is not quite right it should be:[ADSI]"WinNT://$env:computername,computer"

Comment: maybe ",computer" is needed as well

Comment: The user creation works if I add the local user to the Administrator group on the target machine.

Comment: your local computer is not trusted when your local user is not admin

Comment: changing this `$cn = [ADSI]"WinNT://${env:Computername}"` to this `$cn = [ADSI]"WinNT://${env:computername,computer}"`
should work

Comment: cant you do this:`$session = new-pssession -computer foobar1`
`Enter-PSSession $session`
`net user newuser password /add`
`net group administrators newuser /add`
`Exit-PSSession`

Comment: if they user on the remote machine is not an admin, he will not be able to create a new user. You have to be admin to do that. You can get around this by using the [JEA Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn896648.aspx)

Comment: @PeterHahndorf you got confused try again he ment the local user

Comment: @Peter Hahndorf...Thanks for pointing this out. It looks like JEA which is using DSC for creating users will help me to avoid beeing local admin on the target machine. ADSI needs to be local admin and there is no cmdlets from Microsoft that allows to create local users.